# Hive searching for substring with word boundaries

Tags: regex, string, cpu-word, hive, boundary

I'm using Hive, and have a database of strings. I want the rows with certain words, but need word boundaries (if I'm searching for "transport", I don't want a row with "transporter"). How do I do this?

Currently, I'm doing something like the following:

hive> select * from myTable where (length(regexp_extract(column1, 'transport', 0)) > 0);

But obviously this is not incorporating any word boundaries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home) uses [java](/questions/tagged/java) regular expression syntax. You can try the following.

```
regexp_extract(column1, '\btransport\b')
```

If it fails, try double escaping your word boundaries `\\b`

Answer (score 1):

I know that in POSIX compliant regexes, word boundaries are like this: `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`:

```
[[:<:]]transport[[:>:]]
```

However, I don't know if it is supported by hiveQL.

Comment: [[:<:]]transport[[:>:]] works but only for Strings without other words in them (for some or other reason). I found something that DOES work though, since each word was either bordered by a space or "<" on the left side, or ">" on the right side, I went with: 

hive> select * from myTable where (column1 regexp '(.*)[ |<]'transport[ |>](.*)');

Comment: @user3005925: did you try `select * from myTable where column1 regexp '[[:<:]]transport[[:>:]]';`? Because it is strange that you must describe all the string by adding some `(.*)` after and before!